# Check other people repository in gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

We have a course repository in GitLab.
Every member has their own Git repository.

It seems like when one of the members have issues, they share their GitLab SSH URL `git@organizationname:coursename/username1.git`, and someone will go to their repo and try to find the problem.

My question is, How can I check other people's repo on my machine?

I tried to add other people's ssh link remote and can see their remote when in check remote list (`git remote -v`) but can see their repo.

Comment: Don't share credentials like SSH keys. Instead, invite the other users as a member of your project. Then they can view the project in the GitLab UI and clone it using their own credentials. Alternatively, set the "visibility" of the project in the project settings to be "internal" to allow any logged in user to view/clone it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not connect directly to other user's repository.
You clone or pull from other people's repository from your GitLab, assuming the GitLab organization is setup to allow you to do that.

A course repository should come with instructions, [like this one](https://people.nscl.msu.edu/%7Ehergert/phy820/computation/git/), on how to clone your course and contribute.
If it does not explain on how to check other user's code... that might be because it is not allowed.

At a minimum, you would need to be added as a collaborator by the user who want to share their own repository. Then you would be able to clone it.